# How to define a custom binding who use previous value to determine class in Knockout?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I need to bind a table with knockout, and I would like the table cell to get a different css class if the new value is higher or lower of the previous.

I have in mind different possibilities, such as storing the previous value in the bindingContext and have a function which returns the right class, but is it possible to add a custom binding handler which receives the previous value and the new value?

Comment: Can you describe a bit more the scenario? What does previous mean, on the same row or column? A sample data structure would help too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although [Jeff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/390278/jeff-mercado)'s and [Sławomir](https://stackoverflow.com/users/540884/slawomir-rosiek)'s answers would work, I found an alternative that doesn't need any change to the view model nor relies on altering the DOM element object.

```
function subscribeToPreviousValue(observable, fn) {
  observable.subscribe(fn, this, 'beforeChange');
}

ko.bindingHandlers['bindingWithPrevValue'] = {
  init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
    var observable = valueAccessor();
    var current = observable();

    console.log('initial value is', current);

    subscribeToPreviousValue(observable, function (previous) {
      console.log('value changed from', previous, 'to', current);
    });
  }
};
```

Naturally, that will only work if the bound property is an observable.

Answer (score 2):

I looked into knockout [source](https://github.com/SteveSanderson/knockout/blob/master/src/subscribables/observable.js) and I suppose that you can't access previous value inside update method of bindingHandler but you can store it inside element

```
ko.bindingHandlers['bindingWithPrevValue'] = {
    update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        var prevValue = $(element).data('prevValue');
        var currentValue = valueAccessor();
        $(element).data('prevValue', currentValue());

        // compare prevValue with currentValue and do what you want
    }
};
```

Comment: sure you can. the `update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext)` gives you access to the entire viewModel and the bindingContext, and that is enough to figure out quite many things.

Comment: @VladStirbu it looks like you know what I need, could you please detail it?

Comment: [Jeff Mercado](http://stackoverflow.com/users/390278/jeff-mercado) already [answered](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15056351/1977815) the question. Extend the value that you want to track, then bind the cell to the cssClass function `data-bind="css: cssClass"`

Answer (score 2):

What you could do is create an extender to extend the observables that you wish to track the previous values of.  You could then inspect the previous value to do as you wish.

Just pass in the name of the property that will hold the previous value.

```
ko.extenders.previousValue = function (target, propertyName) {
    var previousValue = ko.observable(null);

    target[propertyName] = ko.computed(previousValue);

    target.subscribe(function (oldValue) {
        previousValue(oldValue);
    }, target, 'beforeChange');

    return target;
};
```

Then to use it:

```
function ViewModel() {
    this.value = ko.observable('foo').extend({ previousValue: 'previousValue' });
}

var vm = new ViewModel();

console.log(vm.value()); // 'foo'
console.log(vm.value.previousValue()); // null

vm.value('bar');

console.log(vm.value()); // 'bar'
console.log(vm.value.previousValue()); // 'foo'
```

In your case, you could probably use something like this:

```
function TableCell(value) {
    this.value = ko.observable(value).extend({ previousValue: 'previousValue' });
    this.cssClass = ko.computed(function () {
        // I'm assuming numbers
        var current = Number(this.value()),
            previous = Number(this.value.previousValue());

        if (current < previous)
            return 'lower';
        else if (current > previous)
            return 'higher';
    }, this);
}
```

Comment: Jeff: This is looking so promising for me, but I'm getting null back from ko.extenders.previousValue for every row. Can't figure out where I'm going wrong.

Comment: [Ask a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) and reference this answer and show the rest of your code there. I can't think of any simple cases where this wouldn't work. Perhaps something else in your code is interfering with the bindings or you're just binding to the wrong observables all together.