# Knockoutjs Observable Subscription (loop) - Prevent user from entering wrong input

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

Is it possible to "not change" a value if the user input is not what was expected? For example, the below code works:

```
function data(sno, exp) {
        var self = this;
        self.sno = ko.observable(sno);
        self.exp = ko.observable(exp);
        self.previousValue = 0;
        self.exp.subscribe(function(param1){
            this.previousValue = param1;
        }, self, "beforeChange");

        self.exp.subscribe(function(param1){
            try {
                this.exp(eval(param1));
            }
            catch(err) {
                this.exp(this.previousValue);
            }
        }, self);
    }
```

But, debugging this I realized that the when I change the value of the observable variable, `exp`, using `this.exp(this.previousValue);` triggers the subscription again and this repeats a few times till the value is not different from `beforeChange` and `change` events. Is there a workaround to bypass this repetition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach I followed used a custom binding and a subscription. This solution uses an idea from this SO question/answer here: [How to define a custom binding who use previous value to determine class in Knockout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15055726/how-to-define-a-custom-binding-who-use-previous-value-to-determine-class-in-knoc)

I've created a new Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/joshnicholson/F4bds/1

Here is the Javascript excerpt from the Fiddle. It's best to visit the link to see the full example:

```
function subscribeToPreviousValue(observable, fn) {
    observable.subscribe(fn, this, 'beforeChange');
}

function isInvalid(expression) {
    return expression === 'invalid';
}

function data(sno, exp) {
    var self = this;

    self.sno = ko.observable(sno);
    self.exp = ko.observable(exp).extend({throttle: 200});
    self.writeCount = ko.observable(0);
    self.output = ko.observable("");    
    self.log = function(msg) {
        var content = self.output();
        self.output(content + "> " + msg + "<br />");
    };
}

ko.bindingHandlers.bindingWithPrevValue = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        var vm = bindingContext.$data,
            observable = valueAccessor(),
            current = observable();

        vm.log('Initial value is ' + current);
        subscribeToPreviousValue(observable, function (previous) {
            var newValue = element.value; 

            if(isInvalid(previous)) return;

            vm.log('');
            vm.log('value changed from ' + previous + ' to ' + newValue);            
            if(isInvalid(newValue)) {
                vm.log(newValue + ' is not valid. reverting...');
                observable(previous);
            }
        });
    }
};

ko.applyBindings(new data("000-11-2222", "testexp"));
```

And in the HTML:

```
<input type="text" data-bind="value: exp, bindingWithPrevValue: exp" />
```

Comment: There still exist a loop, though its only twice which is far less than before, there still exist a loop, I assume it is because the change in `exp` propagates back to the computed. Could that be avoided?

Comment: Strange, i'm not seeing that behavior. Maybe you can post a JSFiddle? I see one "write" update every time the user updates the field, not when the computable updates the underlying observable. See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/joshnicholson/ag9vv/7/

Comment: I updated your solution http://jsfiddle.net/lordbalmung/ag9vv/10/ as you see, what I expect is that when I change the value to something wrong, the text box `expComputed` should retain the value, which when I force it, shoots the subscription of the computed observable and it loops through.

Comment: @Lordbalmon i created a new Fiddle and changed the answer to address your concern.  http://jsfiddle.net/joshnicholson/F4bds/ Any invalid value gets reverted... without going into a loop.

Comment: the solution does not work even on jsfiddle, btw I accepted your solution because it was the best :), thank you.

Comment: @Lordbalmon shoot! i posted the wrong JSFiddle in my previous comment. This is the correct one: http://jsfiddle.net/joshnicholson/F4bds/1/  Btw, any value is valid, but entering "invalid" will cause the textfield to revert.